# Find the probability of product of $mn$ to be greater than 30

Tags: probability

Let $n\in A=\{-1,3,5\}$ and $m\in B=\{1,7,9\}$. Find the probability of product of $mn$ to be greater than 30 if $m,n$ are randomly selected.

My attempt was only choice of $n$ was $5$ and then $m$ can be chosen in two ways, i.e. $7$ or $9$. So my answer was $2/9$ but that was not in the options.

Is my attempt wrong or question and options (I don't remember them) that were given in the exam?

Comment: You are correct. The answer to the question you put above is $2/9$.

Comment: What were the options given to you ?

Comment: was $0.222222222$ in the options?

Comment: Had all the events the same probability?

Comment: As far as I remember there was 5/9, 2/3, 5/6 and a couple more I cant recall, but 5/9 was only one with denominator 9.

Comment: @Mirko options had fractions only.